# c++ взаимодействие с fortran

Tags: c++, fortran

Как можно использовать фортран функций в С++?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Я как-то раз делал это на GCC, вот так:

<sup>(Позарез нужен был [вот этот алгоритм](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins%E2%80%93Traub_algorithm), а переписывать на С++ не хотелось. Взял оригинальную реализацию на фортране, 197х года...)</sup>

Код на С++ и фортране компилируется обычным способом (для фортрана - компилятор `gfortran`, идет в комплекте с GCC), и линкуется в один файл.

В коде на С++ пишется прототип функции, обернутый в `extern "C" {...}`, который потом вызывается как обычно.

Имя функции в прототипе должно быть таким же, как в коде на фортране, но записанное в нижнем регистре, и с `_` на конце.
Если вдруг такое имя не подходит (ошибка "undefined reference to ..."), то нужно применить `objdump -t файл.o` к объектному файлу, сделанному из кода на фортране, и найти нужное имя в списке функций.

Типы параметров для прототипа можно подобрать на глазок. Если никак не получается (программа вылетает или в функцию приходят неправильные значения), то придется читать мануалы к GCC и выяснять, какие типы из С++ и фортрана соответствуют друг другу.

В комментариях @avp подсказывает, что обычные числа (не массивы) в фортране передаются по ссылке, так что в C++ на их месте скорее всего нужно использовать указатели.

Никакие calling conventions мне указывать не потребовалось.

Comment: Насколько помню в фортране аргументы передаются по адресу (ссылке). Соответственно, передавая все переменные (не массивы), вы предавали их адреса?

Comment: @avp Проверил свой код, действительно передавал указатели. Добавлю в ответ.